# Power BI-Move on to the next working day

Tags: powerbi

How can I use the Weekday formulae in powerBI?

The objective is if the current day is Saturday add 2 days to make it Monday(next working day) and if the current day is Sunday add 1 day to make it Monday and if its friday then add 3 days to make it the next working day.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have at present? That will give readers something of an insight into what you're doing, and what you need.

Comment: As @halfer said, and what do you mean exactly with `move on`? Are you calculating something? Do you only want to display weekdays?